Could not find org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:7.6
Gradle Build fails with "Could not find org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:7.6". What is the cause and how can I fix this?**
I am currently facing an issue while trying to build my project using Gradle. When I run gradle test, I receive the following error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'testgl'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.   
> Could not find org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:7.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gradle/gradle-tooling-api/7.6/gradle-tooling-api-7.6.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/gradle/gradle-tooling-api/7.6/gradle-tooling-api-7.6.pom
     Required by:
         root project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.        
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.11.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Configuration cache entry stored.

My build.gradle file looks like this:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:7.6'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.26'
    implementation files('libs/xxx.jar')
    implementation gradleApi() 
    implementation localGroovy() 
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'testgl.test1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['C:/vscode/test1/app/src/main/java']
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'testgl.test1'
        )
    }
}

What I’ve tried so far:

I’ve checked that gradle-tooling-api:7.6 is listed in the Maven Central repository, but I am unable to resolve it during the build.
I’ve cleaned the project and rebuilt it, but the error persists.
Running the build with the --stacktrace flag didn’t provide additional useful information.
I’ve confirmed that I am using a compatible version of Gradle, but the problem remains.

My questions:

What is causing the error that gradle-tooling-api:7.6 cannot be found?
How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to use a different version of gradle-tooling-api?
Can I safely remove the dependency, or do I need it for some Gradle functionality?
Where can I find the documentation or resources that specifically address this issue? I’ve had difficulty finding specific guidance online.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

The Gradle tooling API is not at Maven Central, as this search shows.
Instead, Gradle have it published at their own repo, as their documentation explains. This therefore should work:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:7.6'
    }
}

